# Use Xdebug with PhpStorm and WSL

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use WSL (Ubuntu 16.14) from Windows 10 as a web server with PHP 7.1 fpm and Apache.

I want to use Xdebug from PhpStorm 2018 with WSL but it's not working well.

Xdebug is installed on my Ubuntu server and it works well, I see it on `phpinfo()` output.

Here the php.ini config for Xdebug:

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=On
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
```

I configured the port in php storm as 9001 too.

The problem is more on the connection between PhpStorm and WSL. I try it with the remote way. In the `Run > Edit config` popup, I use PHP Web Page and when I use the Validate tools, all is OK except the remote host.
I set it to 127.0.0.1 and this is the point.

When I listen the debugging tools, it said : Port 9001 is busy

How can I do a link between localhost and localhost ?

Comment: The config should work. I have not tried it with PhpStorm but it works for me using VS/Code and a hosts entry. Here is a guide. https://blog.devsense.com/en/2018/04/wsl

Comment: check to see if some process is already listening on 9001. On some distros, the xdebug and php-fpm port(s) are the same, leading straight to your situation.

Comment: Indeed it looks like PhpStorm cannot listen the port because another app has already occupied it.

Comment: 9001 is the default port for php-fpm ?

Comment: The default FPM port is 9000.

Comment: Duplicated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70002223/xdebug-always-listening-for-new-requests-and-prevents-webpages-from-loading-in-c/70084012

Answer (score 1):

I am using WSL (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) from Windows 10 as a web server with PHP 7.4 fpm and Apache with Xdebug Version 3.0.4

Following are the steps followed to configure the Xdebugger in the PHPSTORM and it works for me :

1. Install the Xdebug
2. select wsl in cli interpretor
3. To get the client_host run the  **ifconfig**  in ubuntu or **ipconfig** in bash
4. Open the below file

```
sudo vi /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
```

add below in the above file

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=[ip4 address/Client_host]
xdebug.remote_connect_back=On
xdebug.client_port="9003"
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

5. Then use the Xdebugger chrome extension (xdebugger helper)
6. Restart the apache server.
7. Add the breakpoint to the file and refresh the page

Comment: This doesn't work.