# Xdebug always listening for new requests and prevents webpages from loading in case I don't listen

Tags: php, xdebug, php-7, php-7.4, xdebug-3

I have a strange setup on my new workplace and it works like this: if I have PhpStorm running and have "Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections" on, then my local PHP application works fine. As soon as I close PhpStorm completely (and consequently stop listening to PHP debug connections), then my webpage is not loading (nginx times out after a minute).

Here is my xdebug.ini config:

```ini
xdebug.mode=debug 
xdebug.start_with_request=no 
xdebug.discover_client_host=no
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1 
xdebug.log_level=0 
;xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

Here is the output of `php -i | grep -i xdebug`:

```
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini,
    with Xdebug v3.1.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
xdebug
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support
             Enabled Features (through 'xdebug.mode' setting)
xdebug.auto_trace => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.client_discovery_header => no value => no value
xdebug.client_host => 127.0.0.1 => 127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port => 9003 => 9003
xdebug.cloud_id => no value => no value
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_params => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms => 200 => 200
xdebug.coverage_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.default_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.discover_client_host => Off => Off
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.log => no value => no value
xdebug.log_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.mode => debug => debug
xdebug.output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.overload_var_dump => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_connect_back => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_host => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log_level => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_mode => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_port => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_timeout => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
xdebug.start_with_request => no => no
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.use_compression => 0 => 0
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

Interestingly, I even tried to completely uninstall Xdebug, but I was still having the same problem (I'm not sure if I did it correctly though).

Is there anyway that I prevent Xdebug to make connection? (and have it enable when I actually need to debug only)

I'm using PHP 7.4.25, Xdebug v3.1.1, and running it under WSL on Windows (Ubuntu 20.04). I'm also running everything behind nginx v1.21.4.

**Update 1:**
As @LazyOne asked, here is my xdebug_info() output:

[screenshot of xdebug_info output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q49cb.png)

[second part of xdebug_info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0v2H.png)

**Update 2**

Here is the output of /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=no
xdebug.discover_client_host=no
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.log_level=0
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms=0
;xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
#zend_extension=xdebug.so
#xdebug.mode=debug
#xdebug.start_with_request=yes
#xdebug.start_upon_error=yes
#xdebug.discover_client_host=yes
#xdebug.client_host=10.0.10.1
#xdebug.client_port=9000
#xdebug.log_level=0
#xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
#xdebug.profiler_enable=1
#xdebug.remote_enable=1
#xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
#xdebug.remote_mode=req
#xdebug.remote_autostart=1
#xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
#xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
#xdebug.show_exception_trace
```

Also this is my /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=no
xdebug.discover_client_host=no
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.log_level=10
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug/xdebug.log
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms=0
```

and this is the output of `grep -Ri xdebug /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/`:

```
root@DESKTOP-UB3H2M6:/var/www# grep -Ri xdebug /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini:[xdebug]
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini:zend_extension=xdebug.so
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini:xdebug.mode=debug
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini:xdebug.start_with_request=no
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini:xdebug.discover_client_host=no
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini:xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini:xdebug.log_level=10
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini:xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini:xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug/xdebug.log
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini:xdebug.connect_timeout_ms=0
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:[xdebug]
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:xdebug.mode=debug
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:xdebug.start_with_request=no
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:xdebug.discover_client_host=no
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:xdebug.log_level=0
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:xdebug.connect_timeout_ms=0
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:;xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#zend_extension=xdebug.so
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#xdebug.mode=debug
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#xdebug.start_with_request=yes
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#xdebug.start_upon_error=yes
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#xdebug.discover_client_host=yes
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#xdebug.client_host=10.0.10.1
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#xdebug.client_port=9000
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#xdebug.log_level=0
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#xdebug.profiler_enable=1
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#xdebug.remote_enable=1
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#xdebug.remote_mode=req
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#xdebug.remote_autostart=1
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini:#xdebug.show_exception_trace
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anyway that I prevent xdebug to listening?

No, because it is not Xdebug that is listening. It is Xdebug that makes a connection to PhpStorm, which can be listening for incoming debugging connections.

It is possible that for some reason, Xdebug still attempts to make a connection to the IDE, even if it is not listening. There is normally a 200ms timeout on the Xdebug side when connecting, but I have seen some network setups thwarting that.

In order to find out what, and if, Xdebug is still doing something, make a log file, by changing your `xdebug.ini` to include the following, and then restart Apache:

```
xdebug.log_level=10 
xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

The log file will show you whether Xdebug is still attempting to connect in great detail (because you set `xdebug.log_level` to 10).

Comment: I did that, and actually the log is empty :O - How come?

Comment: I even set the xdebug.connect_timeout_ms to zero, but still not fixing the problem :-( any suggestions?

Comment: @anonyasd Based on the `php -i | grep -i xdebug` output it's a CLI config (`/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`). A web page **may** have been served with a different php.ini config used. Make a simple test page with `<?php xdebug_info();` there, call it via browser and show the output here (screenshots of that table). Do those Xdebug config changes that you did are actually there? P.S. Config files will be shows in `phpinfo()` output.

Comment: @LazyOne as you suggested, I've added the screenshot to the question. Here is the link for your reference (also added on question): https://i.stack.imgur.com/q49cb.png

Comment: @LazyOne And yes, I have the settings in place

Comment: @anonyasd *"And yes, I have the settings in place"* Sorry but NO. 1) `xdebug.start_with_request=no xdebug.discover_client_host=no` -- check what you have for them on your screenshot. 2)  Check `xdebug.log_level` -- it is `0`, which means "disabled". 3) Check what `xdebug.ini` was loaded here -- `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini` -- the key part of the path is **/fpm/** vs your **/cli/** (`/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`)

Comment: @anonyasd In other words: your config that you have edited before is for CLI. Your web server (php-fpm run by nginx) uses different config. So double check all that, ensure that Xdebug settings are exactly as you want them to be in that **fpm** config.

Comment: @LazyOne I've updated my question with a lot of information regarding ini file/configs. I don't understand why the mentioned configs are not effecting the xdebug_info :-(

Comment: @anonyasd Have you restarted web server/workers after making those changes? Maybe even restart the whole thing (whole WSL). P.S. With `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` Xdebug tries to debug every single request. You need to have that to be `No` so you can trigger debugging via Xdebug cookie/GET param. The log should hopefully tell you more (what happens when PhpStorm is closed).

Comment: @LazyOne I actually restarted nginx, but not php-fpm. Anyway, I had no choice except for bringing any developer's magic trick on the table: I restarted my computer and it solved the problem :D Thank you both

Answer (score 0):

first I installed xdebug with the help of xdebug wizard, then I configured the file like this:

In my case was in: /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host="your local ip address of the machine" for me was 192.168.68.102
xdebug.remote_connect_back=On
xdebug.client_port="9003"
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

Then in phpstorm I configured the mapping of the PHP-> Servers: eg "src"->"/var/www/src", you have to do it with all the folders you want to debug.

And finally I configured the Cli interpreter like this:
[The bin of the php and the remote host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHsVR.png)